# How to use @Input() correctly in an Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular

I have the following template in the parent component:

```
<my-table (loaded)="onTableLoaded()" [objId]="objId"></my-table>
```

The problem I have is that the objId is null when loading the child component.
I can add api call in the child but I want to avoid it. Any idea how to allow
the value from api call in the parent can be transfer to child ?

Comment: If you want to know about @Input, follow [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: What about: <my-table (loaded)="onTableLoaded()" [objId]="objId" *ngIf="objId"></my-table>

Comment: I used ngIf and it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data between components in angular you should use Input and Output properties that they are from @Angular/core library. in order to pass data you should use @Input() and after that bring the name of the property that you want. for example in ts in child component you can write:

```
  @Input() dataEntry:boolean;
```

and in your host component you use this input as a property on child component while the data is in host component:

in the host component HTML you can write :

```
    <child [dataEntry]="....."></child>
```

but for more information you can read the documentation here:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Normally the code should be enough

```
<my-table [objId]="objId"></my-table>
```

So the problem must be on an another side.
First you should name it properly

```
<my-table [childObjectId]="parentObjectId"></my-table>
```

something like that, choose what you think is a good name.

Then you should be able to use it.
If you use the objectId asynchron you need to check/handle it in a lifecyle hook. Here the available lifecycle hooks: [Angular - Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

If this didn't help you should be sure that a value is not empty which you want to insert or you can post your component here.